# reuse objects removed from realm database

Tags: android, realm

I want to reuse realm objects which are once removed from database.

Lets say, I have removed one object from database.

```
Story story = realm.where(Story.class).equalTo("id","id").findFirst();

story.deleteFromRealm();
```

Now, I want to pool the removed object and want to reuse it with different "id"(primary key) instead of creating a new object every single time.

The current implementation does not allow me to do this and throws an exception.

My question is, is there another way to achieve the same thing.
If not, should this be a feature added to realm.

The requested code which throws the exception

```
Story story1 = StoryObjPool.getInstance().getStory();
            if(story1 != null){
                story1.setId(1234);
            }
```

The exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable.


at io.realm.BaseRealm.checkIfValid(BaseRealm.java:348)                                                                              
at io.realm.StoryRealmProxy.realmSet$id(StoryRealmProxy.java:177)                                                             
at com.hn.nishant.nvhn.model.Story.setId(Story.java:98)
```

Comment: can you show the code about `The current implementation does not allow me to do this and throws an exception`

Comment: realm throws an illegal state exception saying the object has been closed as it is removed from database

Comment: I have another idea for solve your problem is you don't need delete object from Realm, just update this id

Comment: id is primary key.

Comment: If I fake your problem I will convert `story` to standalone object by use `copyFromRealm()`, then change the id and save it to realm by use `copyToRealm()`

Comment: that will violate primary key constraint.  Create(copytoRelam()) and delete(deleteFromRealm())  the object from realm, but keep a reference to it.         Now use this object again (it will throw the error as it is deleted from realm).

Answer (score 2):

```
Story story = realm.where(Story.class).equalTo("id","id").findFirst();
// create standalone object that not reference to realm
Story stoyStandalone = realm.copyFromRealm(story);

story.deleteFromRealm();

// save standalone object to realm
stoyStandalone.setId(...);
realm.copyToRealm(stoyStandalone);
```

Comment: I want to reuse the same object to avoid unwanted GC events. The solution does not solve the main problem or answers my question.

Comment: but same object always keep reference to realm

Comment: it says it will create a copy of the object, i am unable to dig into the code, how can you be sure :)

Comment: please check this https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realms.
What is the difference between a normal Java object and a Realm object?

Comment: thanks for your answer,but please look at this https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/1849 , where they even mention this is breaking the zero copy guarantees

Comment: thank you, but I see this merge is in 2015, I don't know if anything change about it ^^. Currently, if I fake this problem I will do like my answer. Still looking for better solution

Comment: This is the right answer. If you want to delete an object and re-add it with different ID, then you need to create a detached copy of it first.

Comment: copyFromRealm() creates a new object which I am trying to avoid in first place. I am not sure how is this the right answer. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It's the correct answer, because what you are asking is not possible with the current API. The Java garbage collector is extremely efficient, so have you measured you have a problem with the GC or are you just speculating?

Comment: Currently, I dont have serious GC issues, but I hate reallocating for objects which I already have. As this answer does not solve my use case, I cant accept it. Thanks all for commenting :)